# How to make a loop that only loops 3 times

Tags: java, loops

I'm a very new Java programmer and I was messing around with the stuff that I knew. I created this Guessing Game program but I only want to allow the user to be able to guess 3 times before displaying that the user has failed and what the number was. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int random = rand.nextInt(20);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1-20: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number > random) {
                System.out.println("Too Big");
                System.out.println("");
            } else if (number < random) {
                System.out.println("Too Small");
                System.out.println("");
            } else if (number == random) {
                System.out.print('\f');
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere at all does that show an attempt to do the loop 3 times.

Comment: `for-loop`?  `while (someCount < 3)`??

Comment: What line do you think is preventing it from letting you guess only 3 times?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's actually not homework, we haven't even learned about if statements or loops or anything yet. I didn't know where to begin to make the 3 attempts so I posted on here hoping I could get some help with this.

Comment: Start by having a look at [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), including [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you!

Comment: Please don't just use the code from the answers here without understanding how it works, like you seem to have done in your previous question. If you look at the tutorials linked here, you will be able to easily write it yourself.

Comment: Dumping homework here like this will harm only you in the long term and will cheat you of learning to learn -- the most important skill needed for coding. And it doesn't matter if it's assigned homework or "home work", work you do yourself. You are really harming yourself by your posting history. Seriously. Why aren't you already looking at books and the tutorials? The links that mad programmer gave you -- you should already have. Shoot, Google will give them to you by simply asking `Java loop tutorial`, probably the first hit -- all it takes is a little initiative.

Answer (score 11):

You need a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

What this does is it initializes a variable called `i` to 0, then loops while `i` is less than 3, and adds 1 to `i` after each loop. This loop should loop 3 times (`i` = 0: loop, `i` = 1: loop, `i` = 2: loop, `i` = 3: stop loop, since `i` is no longer less than 3).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you would like your game to play 3 times. Create a nested loop. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int random = rand.nextInt(20);
    while (true) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To only allow three guesses, count the number of `guess`es. Something like,

```
int guess = 0;
int random = rand.nextInt(20);
while (guess < 3) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number between 1-20: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    if (number > random) {
        System.out.println("Too Big");
        System.out.println("");
    } else if (number < random) {
        System.out.println("Too Small");
        System.out.println("");
    } else if (number == random) {
        System.out.print('\f');
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        break;
    }
    guess++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry to ask this, like I said I'm new with this. How would I make it so after 3 attempts it displays that they have failed to guess the number?

Comment: Make a boolean variable (true or false) that determines whether or not the user is correct. If they are, set it to true. Make its default value false. After you are done looping, if correct is false then display the number.

Comment: Or, if `guess == 3` (after the loop), they were wrong three times.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int random = rand.nextInt(20);

        for(int i=0; i<3;i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1-20: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number > random) {
                System.out.println("Too Big");
                System.out.println("");
            } else if (number < random) {
                System.out.println("Too Small");
                System.out.println("");
            } else if (number == random) {
                System.out.print('\f');
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop instead or declare counter as integer and check in while loop if it is bigger than 3 just exit from while statement.